# Correct German word for "Monolaurin"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, technical-terminology

What is the correct German name for "[Monolaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolaurin)" (C15H30O4)?

I have found "Laurinsäure" (C12H24O2) but this is a different substance. These two substances have a relation to each other but again, these are completely different.

It seems many languages have trouble translating these two words but it must have an official translation, right?

Comment: Sounds pretty much like many chemicals in German, Sacharin, Amphetamin, Histamin, Bakin, ...source is English, I guess, but behind that, academic, modern Latin?

Comment: My guess is that Monolaurin itself is perfectly fine in German but I have to be sure. The answer below by @IQV confirms this even more. The exact source is unknown to me.

Comment: It sounds a lot more German than English to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [internetchemie.info](http://www.internetchemie.info/chemie-lexikon/stoffe/m/monolaurin.php), "Monolaurin" is correct.